# django create object and many to many relationship in bulk

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Hi I am trying to create multiple objects in bulk with a specific many to many field id specified.
Looking at the documentation found this:

```
>>> e = b.entry_set.create(
...     headline="Hello", body_text="Hi", pub_date=datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
... )
```

This works fine and creates the entry object as well as the many-to-many field relation as well.

So modified this to handle bulk_creates:

```
>>> e = b.entry_set.bulk_create(
...     entry_objects
... )
```

This does create the entry objects however the many-to-many relation is not getting created in the database.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: documentation link:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`.create(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.create) has an override for a `RelatedManager`, which means that it will set the foreign key, indeed if we look at the [source code <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2584783f46922bcb456ceb9700a3726314df65d3/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L795-L799):

> ```
> def create(self, **kwargs):
>     self._check_fk_val()
>     kwargs[self.field.name] = self.instance
>     db = router.db_for_write(self.model, instance=self.instance)
>     return super(RelatedManager, self.db_manager(db)).create(**kwargs)
> ```

this is not the case for [**`.bulk_create(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) which thus falls back on the `QuerySet` implementation, and thus has no "trigger" to then add the items to the relation.

You thus basically do this in two calls:

```
entry_objects = b.entry_set.bulk_create(entry_objects)
b.entry_set.add(*entry_objects)
```

Comment: great thanks! This combination is not working still

```b.entry_set.bulk_create(entry_objects)
b.entry_set.add(*entry_objects)
```
in between we need to get the entry_objects from the database before passing them into the ```add``` method.
Maybe because it needs the pk?

Comment: @akashdeep: forgot to write `entry_objects = ...` before the `bulk_create`.

Comment: thanks! also curious to know what is the difference then between
```entry_objects = b.entry_set.bulk_create(entry_objects)
```
vs 

```entry_objects = Entry.objects.bulk_create(entry_objects)
```

what is the use of ```b.
``` in the first one?